# moving the chess pieces in android

Tags: android

I have designed a chess user interface using table layout. Each layout consists of 8 buttons, so a total of 64 buttons. I used ASCII values for the chess pieces. Now I want to move pieces from one place to another place by clicking the source button and destination button.

Which event is better to use and how is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622403/chess-gridview-how-to-move-chess-piece-by-two-clicks

Comment: Please check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622403/chess-gridview-how-to-move-chess-piece-by-two-clicks

Answer (score 0):

You can use button onClick event.
When you select source set some flag with respect to selected item. And when you select destination change the flag value to default something like -1.